# Logging Oracle Transactions

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How to Log every record updated or inserted by a procedure. The following things have to be logged.

Primary key column, old value, updated/inserted value, timestamp, user.

This should be logged to a text file and not to a table. I cannot use external tools or JDBC to log the transactions. This has to be achieved through only oracle. ?

Is it possible. ?

Comment: What are you going to do with this text file once you have it?  I suppose you could modify the procedure to write this information to a file on the database server using the UTL_FILE package.  That's likely to be a pretty significant performance hit however.  And I'm guessing that's not the answer you're after.

Comment: Does the seeded auditing ability of not satisfy your requirements? Look into XML, EXTENDED to get lots of info to a file.

Comment: Before you build ANYTHING, check out the database auditing feature as @mmmmmpie suggests.